# Laravel $.post for download File?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have **view.blade.php** like this

```
....
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
....
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')}
    });
    $.post('/download_file', {file_name: "abc"}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

In **routes.php** I already set route

```
Route::post('/download_file' , 'DownloadController@load_file');
```

In **DownloadController.php** I write code for create and download file like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Response;
use File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DownloadController extends Controller {

    public function load_file(Request $request){
        if($request->file_name === "abc"){
            File::put("files/abc.txt", "This is content in txt file");
            $file_abc = public_path() . "/files/abc.txt";
            return Response::download($file_abc);
        }
    }

}
```

File **abc.txt** is create on server but browser doesn't download it after **$.post** call. In console.log(data) I see content of file. Thank for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel provides a response type download out of the box. Official documents states :

> The download method may be used to generate a response that forces the user's browser to download the file at the given path. The download method accepts a file name as the second argument to the method, which will determine the file name that is seen by the user downloading the file. Finally, you may pass an array of HTTP headers as the third argument to the method:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);

//OR

return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

so your load_file function should response the file to download like this, no need to add jquery for this.

Comment: I use jQuery because I want after user open view.blade.php it auto create and download file. I change code like this `$headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/plain'); return response()->download($file_abc,"abc.txt",$headers);` But it not work.

Comment: to make a file download just href the user to the route which points to load_file function and your download should start